# DIV appearing below text input

Tags: css, z-index

a div that appears as an autocomplete aid is rendering below a text input (also happens with select elements), I adjusted z-index but no luck.

[image: Autocomplete div under text input]

That black bordered div should be over the white textbox. This is element CSS:

```
form input, form select {
    margin: 3px 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.suggestionBox {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 10000;
    left: 0px;
    top: 20px;
    margin: 10px 0px 0px;
    background-color: #FFF;
    border: 2px solid #000;
}
```

`.suggestionBox` is inside a `.bloqueSuggest` which wraps text input (the one trigerring suggestion box) and suggestionBox:

```
.bloqueSuggest {
    display: inline;
    position: relative;
    overflow: visible;
    z-index: 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle please?

Comment: It's not actually working properly, I had to strip out too many elements but here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/8MkEH/1/

Comment: So you want to get rid of the default autocomplete? just add this tag to the input field: `autocomplete="off"`

Comment: No, that's not it, the default autocomplete shows values written before,my suggestion box shows a list of names similar to the ones you are writing, plus, when you click it takes some adittional actions. I think this is only a CSS issue

Comment: Can't you use a datalist?

Comment: Datalist? is that html or some framework stuff?

Comment: It's built into the browsers, so you won't need to include any libraries or anything. See [official documentation](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/datalist). Or my [example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/39fFL/).